# google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File /home/technophile/snap/skype/common/xyz.json was not found in Docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I have an application written in python and I am putting that in a dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. The python file when independently run executes perfectly however when I run it in using 'sudo docker-compose up' it leads to an error: File not found when The file is there itself.
Here is my Docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  project-name:
    build: ./
    environment:
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: "${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}"
    command: python3 main.py
```

and Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
project-name_1  |   File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
project-name_1  |     client = storage.Client()
project-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 126, in __init__
project-name_1  |     _http=_http,
project-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 277, in __init__
project-name_1  |     _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project, credentials=credentials)
project-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 225, in __init__
project-name_1  |     project = self._determine_default(project)
project-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 244, in _determine_default
project-name_1  |     return _determine_default_project(project)
project-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 186, in _determine_default_project
project-name_1  |     _, project = google.auth.default()
project-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 454, in default
project-name_1  |     credentials, project_id = checker()
project-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 222, in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
project-name_1  |     os.environ[environment_vars.CREDENTIALS]
project-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 108, in load_credentials_from_file
project-name_1  |     "File {} was not found.".format(filename)
project-name_1  | google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File /home/technophile/snap/skype/common/xyz.json was not found.
```

before running the python file I had exported this xyz.json file and the python file run fine. But the issue comes up when I try to run it using docker-compose. I even created the environment variables but that didn't solve either. Please help me out! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a workaround for this. By keeping the Json file in the same folder where Dockerfile resides and adding a `COPY xyz.json xyz.json` to the Dockerfile,It worked like a charm.